# Python Word Search

Tags: python, file, search

There are text files in the root of the project: keywords.txt (there's a list of keywords), a python file and output.txt (there should be written paths, files and subfolders where there are keywords from the file keywords.txt)

```
import os
import re

# Function for reading a file with keywords and creating a list of keywords
def read_keywords_file(keywords_file):
    with open(keywords_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        keywords = [line.strip() for line in f]
    return keywords

# Function for searching keywords in a string
def find_keywords_in_line(keywords, line):
    # Building a regular expression from keywords
    regex = r"\b" + r"\b.*\b".join([re.escape(keyword) for keyword in keywords]) + r"\b"
    # Search for matches in a string
    matches = re.findall(regex, line, re.IGNORECASE)
    # Returning found matches
    return matches

# A function for crawling files in a directory and its subdirectories and searching for keywords in files
def search_keywords_in_files(keywords, directory_path, result_file_path):
    with open(result_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as result_file:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
            for file in files:
                # Skipping unnecessary files
                if not file.endswith(".txt") and not file.endswith(".log") and not file.endswith(".doc"):
                    continue
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as f:
                    for line in f:
                        matches = find_keywords_in_line(keywords, line)
                        if matches:
                            result_file.write(file_path + ":\n")
                            for match in matches:
                                result_file.write("\t" + match + "\n")

# Reading a file with keywords
keywords_file = "keywords.txt"
keywords = read_keywords_file(keywords_file)

# Search for keywords in files and write the results to a file
directory_path = "C:\\"
result_file_path = "output.txt"
search_keywords_in_files(keywords, directory_path, result_file_path)
```

Searches for keywords for a very long time and eventually does not find (output file output.txt - empty).

I even tried to specify the project directory and created a text file there and put the keyword there. Still doesn't find it.

There should be something like this on the output in the file.

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 047E-E051
F:\
+---AMC&FMS_Report
|   |   1Aaron Attendance Summary Report 2021-22.xlsx
|   |   FAR - IT as on May 20 and 21.xlsx
|   |   PV findings and action items december 2021.xlsx
|   |   test.html
|   |   Worksheet in TC - 031 - IT Assets 2020-21.xlsx
|   |   
|   +---2022-2023
|   |   |   Ambernath Engineer - April 2022 to December 2022.xlsx
|   |   |   Attendance Summary Report 2022-23.xlsx
|   |   |
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly change the `read_keyword_file`, you need to get rid of the "\n" in the end of the line.

```
def read_keywords_file(keywords_file):
    with open(keywords_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        keywords = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
    return keywords
```

Your regex is wrong, either loop through your keywords and make a simple search on each line with regex like `.*(\keyword\b).*` or concatenate your keywords to get such a regex `\bkeyword1\b|\bkeyword2\b` and search every line with it

Comment: def find_keywords_in_line(keywords, line):
    # Building a combined regular expression from keywords
    regex = r"\b" + r"\b|\b".join([re.escape(keyword) for keyword in keywords]) + r"\b"
    # Search for matches in a string
    matches = re.findall(regex, line, re.IGNORECASE)
    # Returning found matches
    return matches

Cool, it turned out, I rewrote the function like this. only it does not output in the same form as at the end of my question.
and how to make a conclusion in the form of a directory tree, as in my task itself?